# How can I download report file from using a button on odoo website page?

Tags: controller, report, odoo, odoo-9

I need to download a odoo report using a button on **odoo website page**.
what I did is:

```xml
<a class="btn btn-primary hidden-print cms-print-pdf" t-att-href="'/cms/report/print?id='+str(main_object.id)">
                            <span><i class="fa fa-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <!--<input type="hidden" id="cms_page_id" t-att-value="main_object.id"/>-->
                            </span>
                            Print</a>
```

In my controller

```py
@http.route(['/cms/report/print'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def print_saleorder(self, **kw):
    cr, uid, context = request.cr, SUPERUSER_ID, request.context
    sale_order_id = request.session.get('sale_last_order_id')
    if 2:
        pdf = request.registry['report'].get_pdf(cr, uid, [2], 'x.cms_html_body', data=None,
                                                 context=context)
        pdfhttpheaders = [('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'), ('Content-Length', len(pdf))]

        return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```

But unfortunately I only get the output a webpage preview , But I need to make a download response directly. What SHOULD I NEED TO DO?

Comment: Is your report `x.cms_html_body` set to type `pdf` or `html`?

Comment: Ie, pdf.  I got the pdf as out put also but as a browser preview instead of download wizard

Comment: Good Question, Hope anyone will help you. I also faced the same problem. But I didn't get any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `Content-Disposition` header in your response, indicating that this is an attachment, meaning it should be saved locally instead of being displayed inline [[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)], eg:

```py
@http.route(['/cms/report/print'], type='http', auth="public", website=True)
def print_saleorder(self, **kw):
    cr, uid, context = request.cr, SUPERUSER_ID, request.context
    sale_order_id = request.session.get('sale_last_order_id')
    if 2:
        pdf = request.registry['report'].get_pdf(cr, uid, [2], 'x.cms_html_body', data=None,
                                                context=context)
        pdfhttpheaders = [
            ('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'),
            ('Content-Length', len(pdf)),
            ('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="report.pdf"'),
        ]
        return request.make_response(pdf, headers=pdfhttpheaders)
```

Where *report.pdf* will be the name of the downloaded file.

Some comments on your code:

- In your code the `if 2:` condition is meaningless as it will always evaluate to `True`.
- I don't think that you need to explicitly set set `Content-Length` header, werkzeug will do that by default [[source](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/760a4a95375d1d404b516fd89c2f5dd5c15cf419/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L792)]

Comment: Thanks @naglis I will try.